# std::optional as template non-type parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, option-type, optional-parameters

I want to have non-type optional template parameters in my class/struct.

Of cause I can do:

```
template <bool has_arg0, int arg0>
struct S {};
```

and use `S<true, 123>` if there is value for arg0 and `S<false, 0>` if there is no value.

But would be nice to have just one template parameter instead of two.

For that first I tried to use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/eadEes)

```
#include <optional>

template <std::optional<size_t> X>
struct S {};

int main() {}
```

but above code doesn't compile with error `error: 'std::optional<long unsigned int>' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter because it is not structural`. Looks like std::optional is not suitable for template non-type parameters.

Then I tried to implement my own solution:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/zn3PnY)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
struct Optional {
    constexpr Optional() = delete;
    constexpr Optional(nullptr_t) {}
    template <typename OT>
    constexpr Optional(OT const & val)
        : has_value(true), value(val) {}
    bool const has_value = false;
    T const value = T();
};

template <Optional<size_t> X = nullptr>
struct S {
    static constexpr auto x = X;
};

int main() {
    {
        S<123> s;
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.x.has_value << " " << s.x.value << std::endl;
    }
    {
        S<nullptr> s;
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.x.has_value << " " << s.x.value << std::endl;
    }
    {
        S s;
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.x.has_value << " " << s.x.value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

which compiles and works on recent compilers.

My question is whether there is some standard-library solution for this? Maybe there exists some `std::optional`-like class in standard library but suitable for template params, basically which does similar stuff as my `Optional` class in code above?

Also small accompanying question is what else besides `nullptr` I can use to initialize optional without value? Maybe there is some standard-library definition like `struct null_type_t {};` which can be used everywhere to pass null-value?

Comment: No, there is no such thing in the standard library. Probably for a good reason. As the answer and follow-up comments demonstrates very well there are a multitude of ways to do this. Your question even shows the most basic concept here of combining a non-type template parameter with a bool flag. How to design this comes down to how you want to use it.

Comment: @super: *"Probably for a good reason."*. not sure, restriction in c++20 are still very restrictive. I hope C++23 might relax the rules (as rule of `constexpr` function has been relaxed since C++11. going step by step allows to see possible safe improvement, let time to compiler to implement the rules. Using optional seems legit. Proposed answer seems more an hack (as OP solution).

Answer (score 1):

What about using variadic templates ?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, T...>
struct O;

template <typename T, T val>
struct O<T, val>
 {
   static constexpr bool has_value { true };

   using type = T;

   T value { val };
 };

template <typename T>
struct O<T>
 {
   static constexpr bool has_value { false };

   using type = T;
 };

template <typename...>
struct S;

template <char ... Cs, int ... Is, long ... Ls, long long ... Lls,
          bool ... Bs>
struct S<O<char, Cs...>, O<int, Is...>, O<long, Ls...>,
         O<long long, Lls...>, O<bool, Bs...>>
 {
   O<char,      Cs...>   v1;
   O<int,       Is...>   v2;
   O<long,      Ls...>   v3;
   O<long long, Lls...>  v4;
   O<bool,      Bs...>   v5;

 };

int main ()
 {
   S<O<char>, O<int, 123>, O<long>, O<long long>, O<bool, true>>  s;

   std::cout << s.v1.has_value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v2.has_value << ", " << s.v2.value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v3.has_value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v4.has_value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v5.has_value << ", " << s.v5.value << std::endl;
 }
```

If you can use C++17, you can simplify a little, using `auto` for the type of the value but maintaining the requirements abut the type of the optional for `S` (an optional `char`, an optional `int`, an optional `long`, an optional `long long` and an optional `bool`).

```
#include <iostream>

template <auto ...>
struct O;

template <auto val>
struct O<val>
 {
   static constexpr bool has_value { true };

   using type = decltype(val);

   type value { val };
 };

template <>
struct O<>
 { static constexpr bool has_value { false }; };

template <typename...>
struct S;

template <char ... Cs, int ... Is, long ... Ls, long long ... Lls,
          bool ... Bs>
struct S<O<Cs...>, O<Is...>, O<Ls...>, O<Lls...>, O<Bs...>>
 {
   O<Cs...>   v1;
   O<Is...>   v2;
   O<Ls...>   v3;
   O<Lls...>  v4;
   O<Bs...>   v5;
 };

int main ()
 {
   S<O<>, O<123>, O<>, O<>, O<true>>  s;

   std::cout << s.v1.has_value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v2.has_value << ", " << s.v2.value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v3.has_value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v4.has_value << std::endl;
   std::cout << s.v5.has_value << ", " << s.v5.value << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: This is non-handy for the case when I want specific non-type params and names, fixed amount. Basically variadic case doesn't restrict anything, you can pass whatever you want and you have to do some static_assert on number of arguments and types. But thanks for suggestion!

Comment: @Arty - About the number of arguments... observe that the general case (the variadic one) is only declared, not defined. So you can write `S<123>` and `S<>` but not (compilation error) `S<123, 321>`.

Comment: Basically my case is that I have e.g. exactly 5 possible arguments of different types like bool (first argument), char (second), size_t (third)... If I pass variadic then I have to check if exactly these or convertible types where passed and exactly 5 arguments. Out of these 5 I want any arguments to be optional somehow.

Comment: So I want someting like `template <Optional<bool> arg0 = null, Optional<char> arg1 = null, Optional<size_t> arg2 = null> struct S {};`. When I use such structure I have to pass at most 3 arguments with given types. I.e. this definition restricts number and types of arguments. If I have variadic then I have to write several template specializations for every type. But I want just one definition of my structure so that in structure's code I'll do something like `if constexpr(arg0.has_value) { UseArg0(arg0); } else { do_fallback(); }` instead of specializing my structure 3 times.

Comment: Why I don't want to write specializations of my structure? Because I can have sometimes up to 10-20 arguments. So I want to easily handle them in code using `if constexpr(argN.has_value)` and also to pass them easily like `S<null, null, 123, null, true>`.

Comment: @Arty - What about something as `S<O<>, O<>, O<123>, O<>, O<true>>` or, of you want explicit the type, for every optional, `S<O<bool>, O<char>, O<int, 123>, O<long>, O<bool, true>>`?

Comment: Yes I wanted explicit type for every optional. To restrict clients as much as possible to using specific types. Of cause they can pass some other type, but only those that are convertible to given restricted types. Any way my class `Optional` (provided in my question-post) suits well to what I need. I just wanted to question if there is some standard library solution for that in C++? Like std::optional but suitable for passing as template non-type arguments. Maybe at some point std::optional will be rewritten in such a way in C++23 to be able to pass as template non-type params.

Comment: @Arty - The best I can imagine, for a standard `std::optional` but with template non-type parameter, is `std::integer_sequence`, but can accept zero, one and also more than one value.

Comment: @Arty - Answer modified with a `S` class with five "optional" template parameters.

Comment: @Arty - Added a C++17 simplification that maintain the type requirement for `S`.